# downloads getting corrupted

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04

Within Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS running in oracle virtualbox large packages get corrupted when downloaded. using:

```
sudo apt-get install packagename
```

results in a HASH Missmatch

All the usual steps don't fix this.

running a

```
WGET https://repopath/packagename.deb
sudo dpkg -i /dowloadpath/packagename.deb
```

results in

```
Preparing to unpack /dowloadpath/packagename.deb ...
Unpacking packagename.deb ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /dowloadpath/packagename.deb (--install):
cannot copy extracted data for './tmp/packagepath/lib/libprotobuf.a' to '/tmp/packagepath/lib/libprotobuf.a.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

however if i download the packagename.deb in windows, then move into the var/cache/apt/archives and issue a

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

after a failed installation then it all works. Has anyone seen downloading >200mb files being corrupted within VMs and possibly know a fix?